# Elements inside RelativeLayout not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design a 3D page curl.

In my mainActivity, I have a viewPager which contains pages to be curled. For each page I have a separate layout file.

In the layout file if i just add a text view like below it is showing up fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/PageTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/green"
    android:text="VIEW 1" /> -->
```

But if I wrap the textview inside relative layout, it just shows a white blank screen and textview is not shown.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DemoActivity" >

    <TextView 
    style="@style/PageTitle"
    android:id="@+id/sampletextview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="VIEW 1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone please help me to know why i am not able to use relative layout in my view layout file:

I inflate the view like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)  myAppContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view1 = inflater.inflate(mViewIds[0], null);
```

Comment: put your whole xml file here pls.

Comment: Just added the case for which issue is happening.

Comment: The sample TextView is shown but the one you add via LayoutInflater is not shown? If so, post the code how you add it to the RelativeLayout, it doesn't even have an ID

Comment: make your TextView's height and width wrap_content, its fill whole the screen at the moment because you have given it fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second parameter of the `inflate()` call from null to the `ViewGroup` that view1 is added to. Or post the code where you add it (and include the part where you define the `LayoutParams`).